# Algebraic Topology Artin

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading algebraic topology by Artin, and he gives the following definition.  Let $X$ be a topological space.  We define a homomorphism $sd_X: S_p(X) \to S_p(X)$ by induction.  If $T: \Delta_0 \to X$ is a singular 0-simplex, we define $sd_XT = T$.  Now suppose $sd_X$ is defined in dimensions less than $p$.  If $i_p: \Delta_p \to \Delta_p$ is the identity map, let $\hat{\Delta}_p$ denote the barycenter of $\Delta_p$ and define $sd_{\Delta_p}i_p = (-1)^p[sd_{\Delta_p}(\partial i_p), \hat{\Delta}_p]$.  Then define $sd_XT = T_\#(sd_{\Delta_p} i_p$.

My question is:  what does $sd_{\Delta_p}(\partial i_p)$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$i_p$ is a singular $p$-simplex in the space $\Delta_p$, so it has a boundary $\partial i_p$, which is a $(p-1)$-chain in the same space. By induction, you already have defined the map $sd_X$ on all $(p-1)$-chains of all spaces $X$, so in particular you have it defined on $(p-1)$-chains of the space $\Delta_p$, and you can then compute $sd_{\Delta_p}(\partial i_p)$.

I remember staring at that in that book for a long time! :-)

Comment: Thanks that helps.  However, I was wondering what $sd_{\Delta_n}(\partial i_n)$ would equal?  Is this computable?  I can't seem to compute it.

Comment: Of course it is computable :-) It is defined by a recursive procedure: follow it!