# Artin Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading algebraic topology by Artin, and he gives the following definition.  Let $X$ be a topological space.  We define a homomorphism $sd_X: S_p(X) \to S_p(X)$ by induction.  If $T: \Delta_0 \to X$ is a singular 0-simplex, we define $sd_XT = T$.  Now suppose $sd_X$ is defined in dimensions less than $p$.  If $i_p: \Delta_p \to \Delta_p$ is the identity map, let $\hat{\Delta}_p$ denote the barycenter of $\Delta_p$ and define $sd_{\Delta_p}i_p = (-1)^p[sd_{\Delta_p}(\partial i_p), \hat{\Delta}_p]$.  Then define $sd_XT = T_\#(sd_{\Delta_p} i_p)$.

I've tried for probably 10 hours to compute $sdΔ1(∂i_1)(1/4,1/4)$ and can not. I have no clue how to start.

Comment: People keep tagging this as a duplicate and it clearly is not.  Please do not erase this.

Comment: What question do people think it is a duplicate of?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339295/algebraic-topology-artin?rq=1
this maybe?

Comment: Why are you creating 20,000 proxy accounts?

Comment: What is a proxy account?  I never made an account.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think s/he understands that this is posted under a new account.

Comment: I am legitimately having a hard time understanding the question posted.  I know it may be very easy but I am having a hard time grasping what the definition means.  Not trying to pull anything on anyone. I don't know what a gravatar is.  I just pick a name and email and it lets me post.

Comment: No, it's not a very easy question. And even if it were, that's not a problem. You might want to register an account, and ask to have your posts merged (after all, you have gained reputation already, and it is nice to have one place to keep all your questions/answers together so that you can go back and reference them.) If/when you do register for an account (or if you can remember your log-in user/password from when you posted previously), you can click on the "flag" link and request that a moderator merge your accounts.

Comment: You should create a named account and have all your questions merged.

Comment: Also, is this in the context of a proof? I recommend looking for the equivalent material in Hatcher (available free online).

Comment: (Also, the poster seems to be right that the last time s/he posted this question, it was unfairly closed as a duplicate. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339772/a-question-on-algebraic-topology )

Comment: Don't know if I would recommend looking for this in Hatcher (I don't have it in front of me but I would guess it's probably buried in the proof of excision).  But if you can get your hands on Tammo tom Dieck's book, I think it's in section 9.4 if I recall correctly.